# Options for storing binary data of size 100 MB to 1 GB

Tags: database, performance, blob, storage

If I am planning to store binary data of size varying from 100 MB to 1 GB what is a better option
1. Relational data (this I am assuming would be a direct no)
2. NoSQL DB
3. File system

Also do suggest if anything else would be better (in terms of performance to write and read the data)

Nature of data:
It's a table having 1-50 Million cells. There is not much structural relationship between the cells. They can be considered independent.
The table is never updated. It's an insert only table.
The above information tells me (though limited by lack of knowledge about NoSQL DBs) that a columnar DB won't be much of help. Do correct me.

Thanks

Comment: I have provided more information. Not sure if that helps. Please do let me know.

Comment: How is the data read? i.e. what does the reading program need to know in order to find the data? Does it just iterate all of it? Does access it using a well-known key? Does it need to find it, and if so, does it find it based on information within the file? Some simple metadata? Some complex metadata e.g. labels or an attached JSON?

Comment: The data is read as a whole. We do not need part of the binary data. Each binary data would be stored against a key and the look up is done based on the key.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Filesystem.

Since there are no relationships between the items being stored, a relational DB would be a huge waste of all possible resources.

Likewise for any NoSQL DB which is fancier than a key-value store e.g. [Graph Databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database). Even something like [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) would be overkill.

So the choice is generally between some a key-value store, object storage e.g. [Minio](https://min.io/), or regular POSIX filesystem.

All 3 have both simple implementations suitable for testing and complex implementation with replication etc. suitable for production.

Of those, I would recommend using a filesystem.

A filesystem would be more suitable than a key-value store because the data is big, and key-value stores are generally optimized for quantity and latnecy, rather than size and bandwidth.

A filesystem would also be more useful than an object store or a key-value store because most filesystems have the same API (POSIX), which means that:

1. It's easy to just switch to another filesystem. There are many, many
2. tools to do just about anything with data stored on a filesystem.